# PIT Coverage generation minion exited abnormally

Tags: code-coverage, mutation-testing, pitest

i see the following stacktrace when running the pitest gradle task in my project after adding all the required configurations in build.gradle. Can you please help me on this ? I'm using 1.5.1 version of the plugin.

The changes have been done in build.gradle as per the instructions in https://github.com/szpak/gradle-pitest-plugin

```
7:00:32 PM PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
    7:00:33 PM PIT >> INFO : Sending 46 test classes to minion
    7:00:33 PM PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
    7:00:33 PM PIT >> SEVERE : Error generating coverage. Please check that your classpath contains modern JUnit 4 or PIT test plugin for other test tool (JUnit 5, TestNG, ...) is enabled.
    Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.util.PitError: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally. Please check the classpath and/or enable test plugin for used test tool.

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Private Build
Version : 25.252-b09
Uptime : 1723
Input -> 
 1 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 2 : -Duser.country=US
 3 : -Duser.language=en
 4 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true


Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Private Build
Version : 25.252-b09
Uptime : 1724
Input -> 
 1 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 2 : -Duser.country=US
 3 : -Duser.language=en
 4 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

        at org.pitest.util.Unchecked.translateCheckedException(Unchecked.java:20)
        at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:105)
        at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:51)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:115)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:121)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:87)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)
Caused by: org.pitest.util.PitError: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally. Please check the classpath and/or enable test plugin for used test tool.

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Private Build
Version : 25.252-b09
Uptime : 1723
Input -> 
 1 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 2 : -Duser.country=US
 3 : -Duser.language=en
 4 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

        at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.gatherCoverageData(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:143)
        at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:89)
        ... 6 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Please post your configuration and provide other details about your project, e.g the version of junit/testng that you are using.

Comment: We are currently using junit 5 and the build.gradle is groovy based

Comment: Could you post the actual config so we can see what might be missing or incorrect?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the config details required ? The repository is on java 11 and we are currently using junit 5.

Comment: Your gradle file (or files) will contain a section `pitest { lots of keys and values and things}`

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.5.1'
    }
}         plugins {

    id "info.solidsoft.pitest" version "1.5.1"
}       pitest {
        targetClasses = ['com.test.*']
        outputFormats = ['HTML']
        timestampedReports = false
    } Above are the configurations that i included specific to pitest plugin in build.gradle

Comment: Can you please let me know if we can see this error for any other reasons, as this change works for me in a module and same error occurs in an other module with similar configuration and junit5PluginVersion added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error message, you do not have the pitest junit 5 plugin enabled.

If you add

`junit5PluginVersion = '0.12'`

To the configuration the plugin will be enabled and the tests should be picked up.

Comment: Can you please let me know if we can see this error for any other reasons, as this change works for me in a module and same error occurs in an other module with similar configuration and junit5PluginVersion added

Comment: I'd suggest you accept this answer, then create a new question that shows the exact error that these modules produce, and clearly sets out how they are configured. Paste the relevent config for these modules into the question, and show the structure of the overall project.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the latest version of PIT uses JUnit5, and I was using JUnit4. So, I solved it by migrating to JUnit5

if you are using maven, add the following lines to your pom file:

```
  <properties>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Pitest supports JUnit4 out of the box, and JUnit5 via a plugin. The statement "the latest version of PIT uses JUnit5" is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming because we did not give correct version of junit5PluginVersion
In KTS we need to give config like this

```
    // Configure the PitestPluginExtension
configure<PitestPluginExtension> {
    // Set the JUnit 5 plugin version
    junit5PluginVersion.set("1.2.0")

    // Avoid calls to the specified classes
    avoidCallsTo.set(setOf("kotlin.jvm.internal"))

    // Set the mutators to be used
    mutators.set(setOf("STRONGER"))

    // Specify the target classes for mutation testing
    targetClasses.set(setOf("com.arcesium.treasury.margin.web.service.*"))

    // Specify the test classes for mutation testing
    targetTests.set(setOf("com.arcesium.treasury.margin.web.service.*"))

    // Set the number of threads for mutation testing
    threads.set(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

    // Set the output formats for the mutation testing report
    outputFormats.set(setOf("XML", "HTML"))

    // Set the mutation threshold
    mutationThreshold.set(0)

    // Set the coverage threshold
    coverageThreshold.set(0)
}

// Make the 'check' task depend on the 'pitest' task
tasks.named("check") {
    dependsOn(":pitest")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have any jqwik dependencies. for some reason that messes with the pitest config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).